# Floating IP Addresses for Staging and Deployment

Tags: node.js, dns, webserver, web-deployment, digital-ocean

Say I have two servers and a floating IP address that can direct traffic to either one. If I point the floating IP address to server 1, all traffic is redirected to server 1, and can be accessed at www.mydomain.com.

How do I set things up so I can do staging on server 2? What domain (besides www.mydomain.com) would I access it at? Could it possibly be private so no outsiders can interfere with it? I would then point the floating IP address to server 2 and make it live at www.mydomain.com (and server 1 would be accessed at the other point for staging).

Answer (score 0):

> How do I set things up so I can do staging on server 2? What domain (besides www.mydomain.com) would I access it at?

Whatever you wanted.  Just set up a DNS record to point at that server.  `stage.example.com` or something.

> Could it possibly be private so no outsiders can interfere with it?

For this, you want a firewall.  Check into iptables.  If you're on Ubuntu, `ufw` makes this a lot easier.

> I would then point the floating IP address to server 2 and make it live

Be sure to disable your firewall first.

> (and server 1 would be accessed at the other point for staging).

Point your staging DNS record back at server 1.

A couple thoughts... have you considered tearing down the old server when you've drained traffic from it, and building a new one for your next staging deployment?  Why not benefit from a fresh build every time, with updates on all your packages?  You can use cloud-init for this.  Digital Ocean makes it very easy to do.